# Ignore Null Values in OrderBy Asc While creating CAML Query

Tags: caml-query, caml, caml-renderpattern

I have 3 Columns in my List

Id Name   SortBy
1   A       1
2   B    
3   C       2
4   D       3

and my CAML query is :

```
 Query = @"<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='SortOrder' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>"
```

and I am getting following result :

Id Name   SortBy
2   B    
1   A       1
3   C       2
4   D       3

Null value in SortBy Column is displayed at first place. I want to ignore this null value, null value should be displayed in the end. Is there any way by which I can achieve this

**My Expected result**

Id Name   SortBy

1   A       1
3   C       2
4   D       3
2   B

Comment: @AtishDipongkor Query is working fine only filtering is an issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a calculated column that would calculate if your sort column is not NULL. The formula could look like this `=IF(ISBLANK([ColumnName]),0,1)` and the result can be 'Yes/No'. Now you can make sorting in your CAML by two columns (the new calculated and later your real column):

```
<OrderBy>
   <FieldRef Name='MyIsBlankCalculatedColumn' Ascending='False' />
   <FieldRef Name='SortOrder' Ascending='False' />
</OrderBy>
```