# order null values ascending with caml query

Tags: caml-query, sharepoint-list

I have a customOrder column in list, its ordered by that number ascending.

I want all null values listed after items that has value in customorder.
I wish all null values would be ordered asc as default but not So how can I do that with caml query is it possible?

as you see below all items null values listed top of the table I want them come after items that have value in customorder

[image]

Comment: Are you using server side code or JavaScript to get items from list ?

Comment: Server side. in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is the default OOTB behaviour of CAML query using SharePoint.

To ignore get null values at the end, you should create a calculated column in the list which will calculate if the sort column is empty or not. The formula of that would be `=IF(ISBLANK([CustomOrder]),0,1)` . After that, you should sort CAML by these 2 columns as below:

```
<OrderBy>
   <FieldRef Name='CalculatedColumnInternalName' Ascending='False' />
   <FieldRef Name='CustomOrder' Ascending='False' />
</OrderBy>
```

To create calculated column - follow this link [Create calculated column](https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/calculated-columns-tutorial) and use the formula I mentioned.

Reference - [Ignore Null Values in OrderBy Asc While creating CAML Query](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/161719/8068)